# Как реализовать программу?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gui

Прошу помощи в разработке программы, оригинал на паскале написан и на 32/64 не переписать его и не запустить (досбоксы и тому подобное не подходит). Надо реализовать прогу на форме в C#.
Состав проги - форма состоящая из 3х частей[image: которая представлена тут], в которой сменной является только та, что по середине находится (область, где много кнопок). верхняя зона - приоритетная  не меняется никогда, а на нижней (где надпись СП и кнопки) выводится меню для удобства перемещения между форматами. Работа и управление происходит перемещением курсора клавишами со стрелками (именно так и никак иначе - так нужно), когда я накладываю курсор накакую-то кнопку, то вызывается формат отображения который проицируется на центральную область (кадровая зона). Пример на фото номер 2[image: вот].
Как можно реализовать такой принцип представления информации? Методом wizard или как? Какие есть предложения и идеи?
Программа - симулятор пульта космонавтов космического корабля Союз-ТМА и есть в свободном доступе - [по этой ссылке[3](https://www.avsim.su/f/obuchayushie-materiali-109/polzovatelskiy-interfeys-sistemi-neptun-me-korablya-soyuz-tma-65458.html)].[3](https://www.avsim.su/f/obuchayushie-materiali-109/polzovatelskiy-interfeys-sistemi-neptun-me-korablya-soyuz-tma-65458.html)
Буду рад любой помощи! Просто переписывать все это с паскаля на шарп ну никак не получается, придется с нуля по чут-чуть делать.

Answer (score 0):

Такой принцип предоставления информации реализуется очень просто. На форму помещается три контейнера. Содержимое среднего контейнера меняется при нажатии кнопок.

```
private void prviButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MiddlePanel.Controls.Clear();
    MiddlePanel.Controls.Add(prviUserControl);
    prviUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```